# How to turn string with commas into enum in SQL / PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've got interesting question.

How can I turn `'1,4'` into enum `1,4` to be able to pass it in expression like this:

```
SELECT DICT_ID AS ITEM_ID FROM DICTIONARY WHERE SERIAL_NUMBER IN (#ARGUMENT#)
```

Where `#ARGUMENT#` is `'1,4'`.

In short, I want to make this query work like if we've passed not a string, but numbers.

Why am I passing '1,4' insteard of just passing numbers - well not me passing this string in query, but some application.

I can edit query, but not #ARGUMENT#

Comment: What your need is to convert a string to an array of integer... Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819375/convert-comma-separated-string-to-array-in-pl-sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
select dict_id as item_id
from dictionary d
where serial_number in  (
     select to_number(regexp_substr ('1,2,3,4','[^,]+',1,level)) as id
     from dual
     connect by regexp_substr ('1,2,3,4','[^,]+',1,level) is not null
)
```

Note: I found this on SO some time ago. But I can't find the link any more to give credits to the original author. If anyone knows, I'll gladly replace this with a link to the original

Comment: Well it's not so bad if your answer is dublicating another, it will be simplier to find an answer however

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
      DICT_ID AS ITEM_ID 
   FROM 
      DICTIONARY 
   WHERE 
      INSTR(','||#ARGUMENT#||',', ','||SERIAL_NUMBER||',') > 0
```