# for loop inside a cursor oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, cursor

I have created a TYPE

```
TYPE t_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(15);
```

A function which takes a string which contains ',' as delimiter and the function returns t_array which is basically splitting the string and returning list of values.

```
FUNCTION split_string(id IN VARCHAR2)
...
...
....
RETURN t_array;
END split_string;
```

Now my stored procedure takes in the long string as input, calls the function to split the string and loops through the t_array and returns a CURSOR.

```
PROCEDURE p_get_xxx(p_id IN VARCHAR2,
                    p_cur_result OUT SYSREFCURSOR)
AS
  l_array schema_name.t_array;
BEGIN
  l_array := split_string(p_id);

  OPEN p_cur_result FOR

  FOR i IN l_array.first .. l_array.last
  LOOP
    SELECT * FROM ........
    WHERE ID = l_array(i);   
  END LOOP;
END p_get_xxx;
```

I get a compilation error along the lines of :

> Unexpected 'FOR' in the place of '('

Is there a better way of handling this scenario or am I missing some thing here?

Comment: That plsql code looks very school book-ey.  Just this part "OPEN p_cur_result FOR
for i IN l_array.first .. l_array.last" is just way wrong and looks like copy paste from different examples.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819375/convert-comma-separated-string-to-array-in-pl-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cursor is always opened on a SELECT statement. There is no a way, as far as I am aware, to open a cursor on a `FOR` loop.

It looks to me like you really want to create a SELECT statement dynamically. I suggest something like the following:

```
PROCEDURE p_get_xxx(p_id IN VARCHAR2, p_cur_result OUT SYSREFCURSOR)
AS
  l_array schema_name.t_array;
  strSelect_statement  VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  l_array := split_string(p_id);

  -- Set up the basics of the SELECT statement

  strSelect_statement := 'SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE ID IN (';

  FOR i IN l_array.FIRST..l_array.LAST LOOP
    strSelect_statement := strSelect_statement ||
                             '''' || l_array(i) || ''',';
  END LOOP;

  -- Get rid of the unwanted trailing comma

  strSelect_statement := SUBSTR(strSelect_statement, 1,
                                  LENGTH(strSelect_statement)-1);

  -- Add a right parentheses to close the IN list

  strSelect_statement := strSelect_statement || ')';

  -- Open the cursor

  OPEN p_cur_result FOR strSelect_statement;
END p_get_xxx;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you for the response. My SELECT statement is close to 100 lines - I'll try this approach and keep you posted if it works.

Comment: I tried this approach and printed out the sql generated after all the looping and when I run the sql on my editor, it works as expected. But when I run the actual procedure, somehow the CURSOR is only returning the records related to last element in the array. Did anyone face this kind of issue with CURSORS?

Comment: I suggest that you post another question to address this issue including all the code involved - both the PL/SQL which creates the SQL statement and the generated SQL statement itself. Thanks.

Comment: Posted another question as suggested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35045410/oracle-cursor-not-returning-the-complete-resultset.