# Is there any code on SQL Server similar to Oracle's PIPE ROW?

Tags: sql, oracle

Which code is similar to Oracle's PIPE ROW in SQL Server? I'm Studying Oracle for the fist time, and just faced with "PIPE ROW" in a string of a code, what's the use of it?

Comment: Does [the description in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/PIPE-ROW-statement.html) help?

Comment: Would a table-valued function in T-SQL solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle a function is a stored procedure which returns a value:

```
create or replace function get_number
  return number is
begin
  return 42;
end;
/

select get_number
from dual
/
```

But the returned value doesn't have to be a scalar. If it is a nested table we can access it with the `table()` function and treat it like an actual table in a query's FROM clause:

```
create or replace function get_numbers
  return sys.odcinumberlist is
begin
  return sys.odcinumberlist (23, 42);
end;
/

select * 
from table(get_numbers)
/
```

But if the function is a pipelined function we can use a `pipe row` call to output any value we like. So we can use programmatic logic to determine the output, for instance generating a list of numbers from `1` to `n`:

```
create or replace function get_n_numbers (p_n in number)
  return sys.odcinumberlist pipelined is
begin
  for n in 1..p_n loop
    pipe row(0+n);
  end loop;

  return;
end;
/

select * 
from table(get_n_numbers(3))
/
```

Here is a demo on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6951ec4bf4bc45a0dc0812ebc6a06e0a).

Pipelined functions seem like an incredibly powerful feature but in practice the use cases for them are rather niche. For instance we can use one [to split a string into distinct tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35449587/146325) but using [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35462641/146325) or [xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35450920/146325) is probably faster.